# Need multiple regular expression matches using C#

Tags: c#, regex

So I have this list of flight data and I need to be able to parse through it using regular expressions (this isn't the entire list).

```
 1   AA2401  F7 A4 Y7 B7 M7 H7 K7 /DFW A LAX 4  0715    0836  E0.M80 9 3:21 
 2  AA2421 F7 A1 Y7 B7 M7 H7 K7 DFWLAX 4  1106    1215  E0.777 7     3:09
 3UA:US6352  B9 M9 H9 K0 /DFW 1 LAX    1200  1448  E0.733       1:48
```

For example, I might need from the first line 1, AA, 2401, and so on and so on. Now, I'm not asking for someone to come up with a regular expression for me because for the most part I'm getting to where I can pretty much handle that myself. My issue has more to do with being able to store the data some where and access it.

So I'm just trying to initially just "match" the first piece of data I need, which is the line number '1'. My "pattern" for just getting the first number is: ".?(\d{1,2}).*" . The reason it's {1,2} is because obviously once you get past 10 it needs to be able to take 2 numbers. The rest of the line is set up so that it will definitely be a space or a letter.

Here's the code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var textStreamReader = new StreamReader(
    assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FlightParser.flightdata.txt"));
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
do
{
    lines.Add(textStreamReader.ReadLine());
} while (!textStreamReader.EndOfStream);


Regex sPattern = new Regex(@".?(\d{1,2}).*");//whatever the pattern is

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    System.Console.Write("{0,24}", line);

    MatchCollection mc = sPattern.Matches(line);
    if ( sPattern.IsMatch(line))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", sPattern);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine(mc[0].Groups[0].Captures);

    System.Console.WriteLine(line);
}//end foreach
System.Console.ReadLine();
```

With the code I'm writing, I'm basically just trying to get '1' into the match collection and somehow access it and write it to the console (for the sake of testing, that's not the ultimate goal).

Comment: Your question is not very clear, are you trying to parse the whole string in one regular expression and get matched data into chunks of groups? eg. group1 will match '1' group2 will match 'AA2401 F7' and so on....

Comment: I'm very confused by what you're trying to get out of that flight data.

Comment: Are you asking how to persist data?

Comment: As of right now all I'm asking to do is get that single 1 character from the first line... capture it in mc and be able to access it back. If you run the code I posted, it'll say it matched/captured the whole line and not just the single number.

Comment: I can kind of understand why the question would be confusing. Eventually what I plan on doing is grabbing each bit of the data using regular expressions, and I would have one giant pattern string with multiple captures in it. But first I need to just get one to work before I do anything more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern includes an asterisk which matches any number of characters - ie. the whole line. Remove the "*" and it will only match the "1". You may find an online RegEx tester such as [this](http://regexpal.com/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is not actually formatted as you posted and has each of the fields separated by something, you can match the first two-digit number of the line with this regex (ignoring 0 and leading zeros):

```
^\s*([1-9]\d?)
```

Since it is grouped, you can access the matched part through the [`Groups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) property of the [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20cdsf18) object.

```
var line = "12 foobar blah 123 etc";
var re = new Regex(@"^\s*([1-9]\d?)");
var match = re.Match(line);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // "12"
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression matches the first digit, that you wanted to capture, in the group "First".

```
^\s*(?<First>\d{1})
```

I find this [regular expression tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) highly useful when dealing with regex. Give it a try.
Also set RegexOption to Multiline when you are making the match.